# Implementing an op-amp based circuit that has a given transfer function

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function

I have this question but I am really confused about how to start, can you please give me some helpful hints.

Let us assume we have a DC voltage measured in a circuit, called \$V_{\text{in}}\$. We intend to build a circuit such that it has a transfer function defined as

$$H(s) = \frac{V_{\text{out}}(s)}{V_{\text{in}}(s)} = \frac{s^2+s+1}{s}$$

Draw this electrical circuit. The circuit can be composed of resistors, inductors, capacitors and op amps only.

I tried op amps with resistors and capacitors in a few different forms, but I didn't get the same \$H(s)\$.

Also I tried a few filters but non of them gave me the same answers.

Answer (score 3):

\$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}}\$ = \$\dfrac{s^2 + s + 1}{s}\$

Divide thru by s to get \$s+1+\dfrac{1}{s}\$

Now you have three terms that are summed together and one of them is based around a resistor, one a capacitor and one an inductor. Does this help? I'm not going to do the full job because it sounds like homework.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: At start I simplified first and I knew I can have resistor and capacitor and inductor but I don't know in what order should I connect them together when I want to draw them in Pspice.is there any chance that we can find what kind of filter this circuit can be?

Comment: Treat them as three op-amp separate blocks then sum the outputs in a fourth op-amp block. The three separate blocks are all fed with Vin and the three outputs go into a fourth op-amp used as a summer. Does this make sense? Then if you need to, simplify but I don't think there's much to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

First thing- since the vin is DC, s=0 and H(0)=infinity,
Second- for the case where both input and output are voltages, the degree of the numerator can't exceed the degree of the denominator which is being violated here, so it's impossible to build the circuit in real world.

Comment: Perhaps in its non-reduced form. See Andy's simplification.

Comment: what andy is saying would be right if input was a current and the transfer function an impedance, then you could make a series RLC circuit out of the simplification but this is not the case here.

Comment: @SalmanAzmat It's a three term controller (PID controller) - can you not see that?

Comment: Oh yeah, just read again and realized that op-amps are also allowed,, but still for DC input integral's gonna give infinite output(ideally) or saturate the op-amp in this case,

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can you please verify that this circuit is what the posts are about?

Comment: We're trying to help the OP by not feeding the answer directly. Has all subtlety been lost from the modern world? BTW your circuit is nearly right except for one glaring mistake. I also won't pull you up on the RC resistor in series with CD - this is a theoretical exercise and it isn't needed.

Comment: @Andy, what is the purpose of RC in a real-world application?

Comment: @sherrellbc it's there to limit the gain of that particular op-amp and prevent it trying to close the loop against a signal that has very high rate of change. Same with a real world integrator - it would normally have a high resistance resistor in parallel with the feedback capacitor.

Comment: I see the logic in the case of the integrator (there always exists a feedback path with the parallel resistor), but how does a resistor in series with CD prevent losing the feedback path? If Dv/Dt were really high then the impedance of the capacitor would be negligible and the amplifier would simplify to just the input with a resistance in the feedback loop. Would it be that the gain would rail otherwise (it now looks like an inverting amplifier with 0 resistance at the input -> Vo = Vi*(Rf/0))and RC provides a way to limit this maximum gain?

Answer (score 0):

This is a improper transfer function: The system has more zeros than poles; it is not causal, cannot be implemented, has a strictly proper inverse and has infinite high-frequency gain.

$$\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=H(s)=\frac{s^2+s+1}{s}$$
with impulse response:
$$y_i(t)=\delta(t)' + \delta(t) + u(t)$$
with step response (also with a discontinuity in origin):
$$Y_s(s)=1+\frac{s+1}{s^2}$$
or, in time:
$$y_s(t)=\delta(t) + u(t)+ t$$

**Figure 1**

[image: Improper]
Additional comment on realizable x unrealizable TFs:

**Figure 2**

[image: Improper2]
UPDATE:

Seen as a PID controller,

$$H(s)=\frac{s^2+s+1}{s}$$
has the form

$$\frac{K_Ds^2+K_Ps+K_I}{s}=K_p(1+\frac{1}{T_Is}+T_Ds)$$

Clearly, this transfer function is improper and practically it can not be used as frequency increases, its gain also increases In consequence, practical applications apply a low-pass filter in the D-term, of the form \$1/(T_fs+1)\$. This low-pass filter has the effect of attenuating high-frequency signals. What lead us to a practical PID controller:

$$H(s)=K_p(1+\frac{1}{T_Is}+\frac{T_Ds}{T_fs+1})$$

Note that, for the modified D-term, the high frequency gain is given by \$\frac{T_d}{T_f}\$ (where \$T_d > T_f\$), instead of \$\infty\$, for the pure differentiator \$T_ds\$. Compare with **Figure 2** above (ideal x real).

Comment: Would "s" be considered an improper transfer function? What about "1/s"?